# IQueryable in Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I've read some articles which forbids exposing IQueryable on generic repositories since it is a LINQ implementation. I just wan't to ask if it is ok to use the IQueryable for private use only meaning it cannot be access outside the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its completely OK to use *anything* for private implementation. It does not exposed to the clients of your repositories via API, so it does not affect them in any way.

Actually clients of repositories should depend only on repository abstraction (interface usually). So even public members which are not part of interface used by client will not affect that client.

BTW there is no way to avoid private usage of IQueryable inside repository, thus you are using Entity Framework. Any query you define in your repository is IQueryable :)

Comment: So does this mean that If I change my ORM, I will also change how my repository work?

Comment: @arvstracthoughts actually you will create (completely) different repository implementation if you'll change your data access provider. There is not much common in NHibernate sessions, DbContexts and direct usage of ADO.NET. But interface which repository implements should stay same. I usually keep repository interfaces in domain/core assembly, and create data access provider specific assembly which implements these interfaces. If I switch to different provider, I just use another data access assembly

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply @SergeyBerezovskiy so how will the repository pattern benefit me if I need to create a new repository pattern after I change my ORM?

Comment: @arvstracthoughts benefit is that repository keeps client unaware of ORM you use. Client (you application) uses repository interface. If you will switch to other repository implementation, other parts of application will stay unchanged. Another benefit is keeping data-access logic in one place, and ease of mocking repositories when you do unit testing of other components

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, everythings clearer now, I just need to ask this one thing that keeps bothering me, if the Interface/Contract reside in the core assembly, I believe that the concrete implementation would also be there? or will it be on the DAL assembly? If it would be place on the DAL assembly then the Presentation layer must reference the DAL assembly to implement IoC which I think is not right since the PL must not reference the DL right?

Comment: @arvstracthoughts implementation of interface will be on the DAL assembly. And its not Presentation Layer who needs reference DAL assembly. If you use repositories in presentation layer, then you need only to reference assembly where interfaces declared (i.e. your domain or core assembly). Then you need to give implementation of interface to DI framework (it's not presentation part - its your application logic). You even don't have to add reference to DAL assembly - it depends on DI framework you use. With XML configuration you can point to DAL dll without any references.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54190/discussion-between-arvstracthoughts-and-sergey-berezovskiy).